# Completely hiding a table's rows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two tables that are side by side. A user can add elements to either table, but no matter what, I make the row count in each table match eachother. So if a user adds an element to **table 1**, an empty row with no text that is invisible is added to **table 2**. The purpose of this is to keep all elements below each table at the same position.

However, I have a small problem with this hack. When a user clicks and drags, they can highlight these empty table rows and it looks very annoying.

Is there anyway to make an element, specifically a `tr` table element, not show itself when highlighted over? Essentially I want the element to act as if it had `display:none;` applied, but I still want it to keep it's bounding box.

e.g.: I don't like how you can see the space of the empty `tr`

[image]

Comment: Hi Josh, can you post a snippet of your HTML/CSS/JS, its hard for us to suggest anything unless you show us your code

Comment: @leemo I'm not sure why I'm downvoted for this, but my code is not necessary in this context. I'm asking a question that does not need any provided example code. I told you what my code does, and what the problem is, and in this case providing my code will not help.

Comment: no problem, leave it as is, just dont expect any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was the `visbility` css property. I just applied `visibility:hidden;` to each individual `tr` element.